# Receive zip file, angularJs

Tags: angularjs, rest, download, jersey, zip

I've got a problem when I want to download a zip file from a Rest api,

When the zip file is tranfered from my server (with jersey), I receive it corrupted, ...

I've already tried to put `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` on my $http request but it isn't fixing anything... here's my code.

```
$http.get(uploadUrl, {
           cache: false,
           responseType: 'arraybuffer'
      })
     .success(function (data, $scope) {
         var element = angular.element('<a/>');
         console.debug("data : " + data);
         element.attr({
             href: 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(data),
             target: '_blank',
             download: fileName
         })[0].click();
      })
     .error(function () {
        console.info("fail on download");
      });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this problem in the past. You need to use the `Buffer` as well and trigger the opening of the "Save As" dialog, as described below:

```
var url = (...)
var expectedMediaType = (...)

var requestData = (...)
$http.post(url, requestData, {
  params: {
    queryParam: 'queryParamValue'
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': expectedMediaType
  }
}).then(function (response) {
  var filename = (...)
  openSaveAsDialog(filename, response.data, expectedMediaType);
});
```

Here is the content of the openSaveAsDialog function:

```
function openSaveAsDialog(filename, content, mediaType) {
  var blob = new Blob([content], {type: mediaType});
  saveAs(blob, filename);
}
```

To use the `saveAs` function, you need to include https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js library. To install it, just reference its js file using a tag script in your HTML page.

```
<script src="js/FileSaver.js"></script>
```

I wrote a blog post describing how to fix it: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/11/21/handle-downloads-with-angular/.

Hope it will help you,
Thierry

Comment: Edited my answer with more details

Answer (score 0):

I'm downloading zip in the same way ($http / arrayBuffer) and it works.

I would guess that the problem come from :

```
encodeURI(data)
```

I think you should encode it in base64 (there is tons of exemples out there like https://github.com/niklasvh/base64-arraybuffer/blob/master/lib/base64-arraybuffer.js )

Comment: yes in fact it was an encoding problem, i solved it by erase the data:/ and by using directly the url for the href :)