# Extracting Image Data from response: Angular 2

Tags: angular

The response has the image data but I am unable to extract it from the response.

CLIENT CODE-

```
download() {
    this._http.get('http://localhost:9000/download/' + this._fileid)
    .subscribe(
    data => {
        this.image = data;
    },
    err => console.log('Error is..:' + err)
    );
}
```

SERVER CODE-

```
app.get('/download/:fileid', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.fileid;
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    gfs.createReadStream({_id: id}).pipe(res);
});
```

[EDIT]- I have adapted my code to use CustomXhr but however I get an empty blob with no data.

CUSTOM XHR CODE-

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomBrowserXhr extends BrowserXhr {
  build(): any {
    let xhr = super.build();
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    return <any>(xhr);
  }
}
```

BOOTSTRAP CODE-

```
export function main(initialHmrState?: any): Promise<any> {

  return bootstrap(App, [
    ...ENV_PROVIDERS,
    ...PROVIDERS,
    ...DIRECTIVES,
    ...PIPES,
    ...APP_PROVIDERS,
     provide(BrowserXhr, { useClass: CustomBrowserXhr })
  ])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

HTTP REQUEST-

```
download() {
  this._http.get('http://localhost:9000/download/' + this._fileid)
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => {
      if (res.headers.get("Content-Type").startsWith("image/")) {
          var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(res._body)], {
              type: res.headers.get("Content-Type")
          });
          var urlCreator = window.URL;
          var url = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
          console.log(url);
          this.image = url;
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are looking for is `arrayBuffer()`. Your code will be:

```
download() {
    this._http.get('http://localhost:9000/download/' + this._fileid)
    .subscribe(
    data => {
        this.image = data.arrayBuffer();
    },
    err => console.log('Error is..:' + err)
    );
}
```

But, unfortunately, `arrayBuffer()` is not yet implemented as of beta.13.

You could instead use `XMLHttpRequest`, [Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rv0Uc9IZpbJgbtMHPFFl?p=preview)

```
getImage(url:string){ 
 return Observable.create(observer=>{
  let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('get',url);
  req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
      observer.next(req.response);
      observer.complete();
    }
  };
  req.send();
 });
}
```

Comment: @shiv You are welcome, of course this is just a workaround until `arrayBuffer` or `blob` is implemented in angular2

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it's not so simple at the moment since you can't set the `responseType` property on the request with Angular2 (there is a pending PR for this).

As a workaround, you need to extend the `BrowserXhr` class of Angular2 as described below to set the `responseType` to `blob` on the underlying xhr object:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {BrowserXhr} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class CustomBrowserXhr extends BrowserXhr {
  constructor() {}
  build(): any {
    let xhr = super.build();
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    return <any>(xhr);
  }
}
```

Then you need to wrap the response payload into a `Blog` object:

```
downloadFile() {
  this.http.get(
  this.http.get(
       'https://mapapi.apispark.net/v1/images/sparky_right.png')
    .subscribe(
      (response) => {
        var mediaType = 'image/png';
        var blob = new Blob([response._body], {type: mediaType});
        (...)
      });
}
```

See this plunkr: See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/2ZodNBmv8OVj3LZSrozG?p=preview.

See these question for more details:

- [Angular 2 download PDF from API and Display it in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368633/angular-2-download-pdf-from-api-and-display-it-in-view/35373887#35373887)

Comment: Hi Theirry, I tried your method. But I get an empty blob.

Comment: Hey! Really? Did you try my plunkr? I get this `Blob {size: 8914, type: "image/png"}` in it. Do you add the provider for the `CustomBrowserXhr` class?

Comment: Can you please take a look at my edit in the post. Yes i tried your plunkr. It works fine there. So I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You shoud remove `new Uint8Array(...)` ;-) I updated my plunkr with the complete chain