# Corrupt File download from Azure Blob Storage using FileSaver.js

Tags: angular, azure-blob-storage, filesaver.js

I have a Excel Spreadsheet in Azure that I am exposing using a SAS and after downloading, it says the file is corrupt. Here is the code to save and uri

```
var result : any= {};
result.fileUri =
    "https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/market-files/33b55b3c-8997-405c-af31-33f6f3e79daf?sv=2016-05-31&sr=b&sig=5Xw%2F4UPcdXbXrxd4mIcZUPQX%2FZzVZfDTQoTfr5V6NTY%3D&st=2017-03-16T18%3A00%3A12Z&se=2017-03-17T18%3A05%3A12Z&sp=rw";

this.http.get(result.fileUri).subscribe(
             (response: any) => {
                                 var mediaType = 'application/octet-stream';
                                 var blob = new Blob([response._body], { type: mediaType });
                                 var filename = 'test.xlsx';
                                 saveAs(blob, filename);
            });
```

File is downloaded with correct filename but when I open it, I get an error in Excel saying the file is corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Angular2, but I believe that the response body should be converted to `arraybuffer`. About how to deal with it, you can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36443172/extracting-image-data-from-response-angular2) on SO.

Here is an example of downloading the file from Azure Blob Storage with plain Javascript and FileSaver.js.

```
var fileUri = "https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/market-files/<bolbNameAndSAS>";
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", fileUri, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    var blob = new Blob([oReq.response], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
    var filename = 'test.xlsx';
    saveAs(blob, filename);
};

oReq.send();
```