# File Upload Using Angular 5 Reactive Form and ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular5, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a somewhat complex form with two nested FormGroup. Each nested FormGroup containing a file input field along with other 6 input fields as Follows:

**In the Component:**

```
updateEmployeeNomineeForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
   this.updateEmployeeNomineeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      employeeNominee1: this.formBuilder.group({
        employeeId: [employeeId],
        nomineeName: [],
        nomineeRelation: [],
        nomineeContactNo: [],
        nomineeNationalId: [],
        nomineePicture: [], // This is the file input
        additionalInfo: []
      }),
      employeeNominee2: this.formBuilder.group({
        employeeId: [employeeId],
        nomineeName: [],
        nomineeRelation: [],
        nomineeContactNo: [],
        nomineeNationalId: [],
        nomineePicture: [], // This is the file input
        additionalInfo: []
      })
    });
  }
```

**And the  HTML form is as like as follows:**

```
<div *ngIf="updateEmployeeNomineeForm">
    <form [formGroup]="updateEmployeeNomineeForm" (ngSubmit)="updateEmployeeNominees()">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <strong>Nominee-1</strong>
            </div>
            <div formGroupName="employeeNominee1" class="card-body">

             //Other inputs omitted for Clarity

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Nominee Picture</label>
                <div class="custom-file col-md-8">
                  <input type="file"  #nomineePicture1 formControlName="nomineePicture" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <strong>Nominee-2</strong>
            </div>
            <div formGroupName="employeeNominee2" class="card-body">

              //Other inputs omitted for Clarity

              <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Nominee Picture</label>
                <div class="custom-file col-md-8">
                  <input type="file" #nomineePicture2 formControlName="nomineePicture" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!updateEmployeeNomineeForm.valid" class="btn btn-success text-white"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Submit</button>

    </form>

  </div>
```

**Now the *updateEmployeeNominees()* method in the Component as follows:**

```
updateEmployeeNominees(): void {
    this.employeeService.updateEmployeeNominees(this.updateEmployeeNomineeForm.value).subscribe((updateStatus) => {
      if (updateStatus) {
        this.resetUpdateEmployeeNominees();
        this.updateSuccessMessage = "Employee Nominees updated successfully!";
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.updateSuccessMessage = null;
        }, 4000);
      }
    }, (error) => {
      this.serverErrorMessage = this.errorMessageService.getServerErrorMessageText();
    });
  }
```

**Now the `updateEmployeeNominees()` method in the *EmployeeService* as Follows:**

```
updateEmployeeNominees(employeeNominees: any): Observable<any> {
    const body = JSON.stringify(employeeNominees);
    const headerOptions = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.put<any>(this.baseUrl + 'UpdateEmployeeNominees/'+ employeeId, body, {
      headers: headerOptions
    }).catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

**In the ASP.NET Core Web Api Controller:**

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateEmployeeNominees([FromRoute] int id,[FromBody] EmployeeNomineesViewModel employeeNominees)
{
            //Necessary operation goes here
            return Ok(true);
}
```

**Everything works as expected except the nomineePictures upload..Would anybody help me to bind the image files to the input field while posting the form to ASP.NET Web API controller method.**

Comment: This answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936183/angular-5-file-upload/47938117#47938117

Comment: In this answer you can see how to show image from API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530752/getting-image-from-api-in-angular-4/45630579#45630579

Answer (score 0):

you cannot get image directly.To get the image you have to some workaround.Add `(change)` event to input

In your `html`

```
<div class="custom-file col-md-8">
                  <input type="file" (change)="getfile($event)" formControlName="nomineePicture" class="form-control">
                </div>
```

In `ts` file

```
public file: File;

getfile(e: any) {

  const fileList: FileList = e.target.files;
        this.file = fileList[0];

}

updateEmployeeNominees(): void {

console.log(this.file); // this will give you the file
console.log(this.updateEmployeeNomineeForm.value); this will give you formdata

}
```

Comment: I have already tried what you wrote here..but no luck.. Please write complete code along with asp.net core controller method..according to your present code how the file will be available in controller method??

Comment: you need to send the image along with formdata to get the image in your controller

Comment: what you want im not familiar with asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Use the native browser `FileReader` to read the contents of a file. Heavy disclaimer: none of this code is tested, I just wrote it out of the hat in notepad. You should get the idea if copypaste doesn't work, and intellisense will help with the rest. ;D

*Template*

```
<input #fileInput type="file"/>
```

*component.ts*

```
@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef;
get files() {
    return this.fileInput.nativeElement.files;
}
async submit() {
    if (!this.files.length) {
        console.error('Please select a file');
        return;
    }
    const fileContents = (await Promise.all(
        this.files.map(file => this.readFile(file))
    ).map(dataUrl => this.stripDataUrl(dataUrl));
    // Each item in FileContents is now a Base64 encoded string.
    // Post 'em to server and convert them there to a blob for saving as a file, or whatever you like.     
    // If you want to know the MIME type before posting, 
    // scrap that stripDataUrl() method and extract mime from the dataUrl.
    // DataUrls are formatted like 'data:image/png;base64,xxxxxxzzz'
}

/**
 *  @return a string without the encoding type and mime
 */
stripDataUrl(dataUrl) {
    return dataUrl.split(',')[1];
}

readFile(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
            resolve(e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}
```

You can also show a preview of a selected image:

*Template*

```
<img *ngIf="(thumb$|async); let thumb" [src]="thumb" class="thumbnail" />
```

*component.ts*

```
thumb$: Observable<string>;
ngOnInit() {
    this.thumb$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.fileInput.nativeElement, 'change')
        .filter(event => !!event.target.files.length)
        .switchMap(event => Observable.fromPromise(this.readFile(event.target.files[0])))
        .filter(dataUrl => /image/i.test(dataUrl));
}
```