# Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 at Object.parse while displaying image

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean

I am trying to store image in mongodb and display it back to Angular. I am done with upload, but I am getting error while I try to display. I tested my API in POSTMAN. It is working fine. I think the error is because of the response type.

**API**

```
    get('/images',(req, res, next) => {
      const user = AuthBase.getUser(req, res);
      this.model.findOne({\[this.userForeignKey\]: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id)}, (err, image) => {
          if (err) {
              res.sendStatus(400);
          }
          // stream the image back by loading the file
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg'); 
          fs.createReadStream(path.join(UPLOAD_PATH, image.filename)).pipe(res);
//if I add res.json(image) here, I am not getting any error but the Image is getting broken        
 })
    });][1]
```

**Service**

```
getImage(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(`/api/images`);
}
```

**Component**

```
images:[]
  getImage() 
  {
 this.patientService.getImage().subscribe(
    data =>{ 
   this.images = [data]; 
   console.log(data); },
    error => console.log(error) ); 
  }
```

Comment: Something is assuming your response is JSON,, and not an image. Is this an angular thing?

Comment: what is output in console.log() data of subscribe

Comment: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/images", ok: false, …}
error
:
{error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0 at Object.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHt…, text: "����C↵
 ↵↵

…+�9�ڷ�"�q����X�{�?߄�Silֹ�k��ƶ�����؎1�m/��"}
headers
:
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message
:
"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/api/images"
name
:
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
:
false
status
:
200
statusText

Comment: What's the point of your getImage() service in the first place? To display an image in your template, you need to put the **url** of the image in the src property, and the browser will load the image. So loading the image using a AJAX request isn't needed.

Comment: <div *ngFor="let img of images">
       <img [src]="img.url"  class="img-rounded" alt="Cinque Terre">
            </div>  I am doing this

Comment: But your REST service doesn't return a JSON object (img) with a url property. It returns the bytes of the JPEG image. All you need is `<img src="/api/images" .../>`: the browser will then load the bytes of the image returned by your REST service by making a request to /api/images.

Comment: I am  using JWT token for authorization and session. So If i use `<img src="/api/images" .../>` It is showing 401 **unauthorized**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the response type with get request

```
getImage(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(`/api/images`,{ responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

Comment: `Blob(23413) {size: 23413, type: "image/jpeg"}
size:23413
type:image/jpeg"
proto__:Blob` I am getting this in console.  Unexpected  token in JSON error is gone now. But I am not able to display image

Comment: you need to convert your blob to image format check this for convert blob to image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530752/getting-image-from-api-in-angular-4