# Image response to blob, file or other resource

Tags: angular, image, api, typescript, download

I have a strange responde from an external API

```
ok:true
status:200
statusText:"OK"
type:2
_body:"�PNG↵↵IHDR�X:�(��IDATx��6��g��L&��s�I4�ƅ�G\QTQ#���Ib�Ep�w# (�
```

The body responde is an PNG. 
when the API URL is open on a tab the image is well displayed.

The question is: 
How can I make this image to a File, Blob or something in Typescript to download it. 
Or how using that response make the image download in typescript.

Comment: Might be a base64 encoded image. What API is it and how are you accessing it

Comment: This  is a PNG binary being received as a string. Set the [responseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) to blob..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Image from API in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530752/getting-image-from-api-in-angular-4)