# Parsing PNG from response (without default JSON parsing)

Tags: json, angular, typescript, http, httprequest

After trying many things read here, i still couldn't find a solution to this particular problem:
I make a request from angular (localhost:4200) to an API on spring (localhost:8080), I have an HttpService that handles request just fine, until I have to make a request which response is not a JSON, but an image/png:

```
private httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Accept': 'image/png',
  'Content-Type': 'image/png'
  })
};

constructor(private http: HttpService) { }

getVehicleQr(vehicleId: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('/vehicle/qr/' + vehicleId, this.httpOptions);
}
```

I've set the Accept and Content-Type headers in the httpOptions, yet when I execute the getVehicleQr() method, I get this error:
[image: error]

this suggest that Angular is still trying to parse a JSON where i set it not to.
Any suggestions? full code can be found [here.](https://github.com/AriMirra/kelvin)

I've also seen [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530752/getting-image-from-api-in-angular-4-5)

Comment: Probably unrelated, but still incorrect: don't set "Content-Type" - it refers to the request content (which there is none).

Comment: You posted a relevant link.  Please tell us why you didn't use { responseType: 'blob' } and handle the returned blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was actually simple, as [rickz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1110291/rickz) pointed to, I had to add

```
{ responseType: 'blob' }
```

in the HttpRequest Options, as is not an HttpHeader (as I originally thought) but a separate argument of the HttpRequest.

Thanks for the help!