# Angular <img src> Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm loading some images from a service like suggested in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530752/getting-image-from-api-in-angular-4-5/45630579#45630579) but sometimes I get the error `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. 
I'm using Angular 7, I tried changing the `load` option in

```
reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
```

with `loadend`hoping that it will trigger in a different way, but I discovered that it don't different from `load`, but it will trigger also when the load fails.

Here is the full error in console:

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.match (<anonymous>)
    at _sanitizeUrl (core.js:11206)
    at DomSanitizerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DomSanitizerImpl.sanitize (platform-browser.js:1817)
    at setElementProperty (core.js:21108)
    at checkAndUpdateElementValue (core.js:21060)
    at checkAndUpdateElementInline (core.js:21007)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23358)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23324)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23958)
    at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.js:23944)
```

Edit adding requested code:

```
  getMainImageFromService() {
    this.mainImageLoading = true;
    this.vehicleImageWebService.getImage('1').subscribe(data => {
      this.createImageFromBlob(data);
      this.mainImageLoading = false;
    }, error => {
      this.mainImageLoading = false;
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
  createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
      this.mainImage = reader.result;
    }, false);

    if (image) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  }
```

Edit2:

```
<img [src]="mainImage" style="max-width: 100%" *ngIf="!mainImageLoading && mainImage">
```

Comment: it means that somewhere in your code, you are calling a function which in turn calls another function and so forth, until you hit the call stack limit.

Comment: Could you please show the binding and the code inside the load listener?

Comment: post the code  where you have bind the image url  and also if you are using DomSanitizer to sanitize the  url  then post that part too

Comment: Code added as requested

Comment: @DavideQuaglio can you please  post the html part too ? means the image binding in the template

Comment: @DavideQuaglio I am facing the same issue. Have you manage to fix it. Can you please help me with it.

Comment: @user2423768 yes, I needed to change the implementation...Here is what I'm doing, image is of type Blob.
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(image))