# ngfor template in Angular 2 and argument in function is not working

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I made [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/gHnKDlVwOTW5TCEvgpo6?p=preview) to show you what I want to get.

Actually the first part is working well but when I want to put it in a `ngfor` and nothing is working as intended.

What's working :

```
<div>
  <button (click)="showDownloadLink(link1)" flex="auto">CLICK ON ME SENPAI ! </button>
  <a id="test_link" #link1 href="" (mouseover)="in()" (mouseout)="out()" hidden> Jquery should execute on hover </a>
</div>

<div>
  <button (click)="showDownloadLink(link2)" flex="auto">CLICK ON ME SENPAI 2 ! </button>
  <a id="test2_link" #link2 href="" (mouseover)="in()" (mouseout)="out()" hidden> Jquery  2should execute on hover </a>
</div>
```

What's not working :

```
<div *ngFor="#link of links">
  <button (click)="showDownloadLink(link)" flex="auto">CLICK ON ME SENPAI ! </button>
  <a id="test_link" #link href="{{link}}" (mouseover)="in()" (mouseout)="out()" hidden> Jquery should execute on hover </a>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT  : Both answer are working perfectly but can't accept both

Comment: Any reason why you use `Renderer` instead of normal template binding?

Comment: Yes there is a reason. But can't explain why on this post ^^" Look on it : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568082/open-download-link-in-javascript-angular2/36568320?

Comment: It's really messy and I don't found the source of the problem yet ... :/

Comment: Not sure what problem you're referring to. The download link issue?

Comment: haw .... sorry , bad link ... !  ... I don't know why ( and my collegues neither ) but the link is decorated with the context of the apps before being rendered on the page ... :/ And it's only in the case that the url is given throught a var.
If it's why a simple url ( String ) it's not decorated ... :/ ( I'll try to make a question about that problem later .... :/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following instead:

```
<div *ngFor="#link of links">
  <button (click)="showDownloadLink(linkElt)" flex="auto">CLICK ON ME SENPAI ! </button>
  <a id="test_link" #linkElt [href]="link" (mouseover)="in()" (mouseout)="out()" hidden> Jquery should execute on hover </a>
</div>
```

In you case, you had two variables with the same name:

- link that corresponds to the current element of the loop (type string)
- link that corresponds to the dom element of the `a` tag

There was a conflict at this level and the string variable was used (instead of the DOM element one) and you had the following error:

```
VM489 angular2.dev.js:23501TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined
 at BrowserDomAdapter.setAttribute (VM489 angular2.dev.js:23774)
 at DomRenderer.setElementAttribute (VM489 angular2.dev.js:13819)
 at DebugDomRenderer.setElementAttribute (VM489 angular2.dev.js:7283)
 at App.showDownloadLink (VM492 app.ts!transpiled:29)
 (...)
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/NLCqRcs7ZiQi01d0o6eU?p=preview.

Comment: [attr.href] need to replace the href ? Oo any reason about that ?

Comment: `href` is actually a property of the `a` tag so it's even better to use property binding instead of attribute binding. I updated my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 2):

`#link` in

```
<div *ngFor="let link of links">
```

is shadowing the `#link` in

```
<a id="test_link" #link
```

Changing the name makes it work

```
  <button (click)="showDownloadLink(linkx)" flex="auto">CLICK ON ME SENPAI ! </button>
  <a id="test_link" #linkx href="{{link}}" (mouseover)="in()" (mouseout)="out()" hidden> Jquery should execute on hover </a>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/HU3R1uJPM4Li4WkjPLvy?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your response ! :) Both explain where is the problem :)