# Saving Blob as xlsx in Angular2

Tags: angular, blob

I have some issues with saving `xlsx` in my Angular2 app:

```
this._http.get('/api/file).subscribe(success=>{
                var blob = new Blob([success.json()], {
                    type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
                });
                var downloadUrl= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                window.open(downloadUrl);

            }, error=>{

            });
```

The response I receive from backend is in the following form:

```
PK�q�H_rels/.rels���j�0��}
�{㴃1F�^Ơ�2��l%1I,c�[��3�l
l�����H��4��R�l��·����q}*�2�������;�*��
t"�^�l;1W)�N�iD)ejuD�cKz[׷:}g����@:�.... etc
```

Any ideas where I am doing mistake?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that binary response content isn't supported out of the box. You need to "manually" set the response type on the underlying XHR object

As a workaround, you need to extend the `BrowserXhr` class of Angular2 as described below to set the `responseType` to `blob` on the underlying xhr object:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {BrowserXhr} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class CustomBrowserXhr extends BrowserXhr {
  constructor() {}
  build(): any {
    let xhr = super.build();
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    return <any>(xhr);
  }
}
```

Be careful when registering this class in providers since it's global. You should set it only within the component that execute the request. In you case, you get a string representation of response data...

```
@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [
    provide(BrowserXhr, { useClass: CustomBrowserXhr })
  ]
})
export class ...
```

Then you need to get data from the `_body` property of the response object. You should use normally since it's an internal one but there is no other way right now:

```
this._http.get('/api/file).subscribe(success => {
  var blob = new Blob([success._body], {
               type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
  });
  var downloadUrl= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(downloadUrl);
}, error=>{
  (...)
});
```

See this question for more details:

- [Angular 2 download PDF from API and Display it in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368633/angular-2-download-pdf-from-api-and-display-it-in-view/35373887#35373887)

Comment: thats great! i am testing, and i will let you know how is it going

Comment: It was working, but it isn’t with the current angular2 version. `_body` is private now but you can access it with `success['_body']` .