# XMLHttpRequest file upload returning a 500 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to upload a file using XMLHttpRequest() but the post request is returning a 500 internal server error. I've made sure the file parameter is sending through the file object and that the action URL is correct. Am I missing something?

HTML:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="documents" (change)="onFileUploadChange($event)">
```

Component:

```
onFileUploadChange(_event: any) {
    let file = _event.srcElement.files;
    let postData: any = null; 
    this._fileUploadService.uploadFile(this.uploadURL, file);
}
```

Service:

```
uploadFile(_url:string,_file:File):Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var xhr:XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

        console.log(_file);
        console.log(_file[0].name);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    // ...
                } else if (xhr.status === 500) {
                    // ...
                }
                else {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        };

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', _file[0], _file[0].name);

        xhr.open('POST', _url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');


        xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
```

Comment: You have an internal server error. Debug your server side code to find out what the problem is. If something is wrong with the request, that will tell you what.

Comment: Solved. It was a server error.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error means the request got to the destination and there was a problem at the destination. Try checking the destination for errors.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you send wrong request? Last time I've got the same problem and there was a solution:

[Saving Blob as xlsx in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769419/saving-blob-as-xlsx-in-angular2/36770048#36770048)