# Angular2 file download with Asp.Net MVC is always named 'download.xlsx' - how do I change the name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, xlsx

Controller method:

```
public FileResult FromModel(ExcelWorkBook model)
{
    byte[] fileBytes;
    var reportStream = ExcelCreator.Create(model);
    try
    {
        fileBytes = reportStream.ToArray();
        var fileName = "some_crazy_filename.xlsx";

        var encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        Response.Charset = encoding.WebName;
        Response.HeaderEncoding = encoding;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition { FileName = fileName, Inline = true }.ToString());
        return File(fileBytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    }
    catch (Exception) { throw; }
    finally
    {
        reportStream.Close();
        reportStream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Angular2 method:

```
this.http.post('/Excel/FromModel', postData, { headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer })
    .catch(this.handleError)
    .subscribe(x => {
        console.log(x);
        let blob = new Blob([x.arrayBuffer()], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        fileReader.onloadend = function (readerEvent) {
            window.open(fileReader.result);
        };
    });
```

The file is downloaded perfectly, but the filename is always **download.xlsx** any idea what I am missing?  I feel like I am missing something easy... thank you!

Comment: Why bother downloading the file asynchronously if you're only going to save it via `window.open` (which is where you lose the filename, btw)?  Browsers are still pretty awful about this.  You (probably) won't find a better solution than `window.open`ing the download URL so the browser can get the correct headers and apply the filename to the download.

Comment: I just want to download the file without doing a postback - I have no idea how to do that with Angular2 and a post.  A synchronous solution would be fine!

Comment: I don't have one, sorry.  I just got working on mass downloads through a browser, and I hit my head up against this issue.  Had a post that returned a file and I had to process a bunch of them.  After trying a number of things, all of which sucked or failed for whatever reason on browser x or y, I converted the post call to a get call and opened the bloody thing in a new tab.  It worked, and was cross-browser compatible.  I'm not saying that's the only solution, but it was the only one I could find that was reliable.  I still can't get clean enough.  Brb, shower.

Comment: well at least I'm not the only one :P

Comment: ugh... so easy :P  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240796/angular-2-best-approach-to-use-filesaver-js

Comment: from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240796/angular-2-best-approach-to-use-filesaver-js