# Set The Name of a ZipArchive Zip File In Web API

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api2, httpresponsemessage, c#-ziparchive

I can't seem to set a zip file's name from a web API in a `HttpResponseMessage`. I can successfully create the zip file using ZipArchive with all its content files, but when downloading it from client side (although it does return and open successfully) the name appears in a 16-byte hexadecimal format like a guid. I would like to set a custom name for my zip file. Where should I do this?

Setting the `ContentDisposition` doesn't work:

```
responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
     FileName = attachmentName
};
```

From the client side using Angular2+ I return the file as a blob:

```
DownloadAtachment(url: string): Observable<Blob> { 
 const requestHeaders = new Headers(
    {
        'Content-Type', 'application/json',
        'Accept', 'application/zip'
    },
 );

 let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: requestHeaders });
 let args: RequestOptionsArgs = {headers: options, withCredentials:false, responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer};

 return this._http.get(url, args)
    .map(response => {
        return new Blob([response.blob()], { type: 'application/zip'});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `file-saver` js library (check [Angular 2 Best approach to use FileSaver.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240796/angular-2-best-approach-to-use-filesaver-js)) or `ngx-filesaver`, more info here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filesaver

Comment: This seems like a work-around, although it could be a solution if the web API does not allow an zip file name to be set in the `HttpResponseMessage`.

Comment: @Jnr try to add header responseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", attachmentName);

Comment: also change responseType: ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer to ResponseContentType.Blob

Comment: Tried both of those, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not entirely sure why the HttpResponseMessage headers are not used, but I just used a different way to handle the response. So instead of using the following to open the blob:

```
const fileurl = URL.createObjectURL(res);
window.open(fileurl, '_self');
```

I used a `@ViewChild` to access an invisible anchor tag to handle the click and set attachment name:

```
const fileurl = URL.createObjectURL(res);
const link = this.zipClick.nativeElement as HTMLAnchorElement;
link.href = fileurl;
link.donwload = "Name.zip";
link.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to download it with Angular's HttpClient, you can simple create an `<a [href]="url" target="_blank">Download zip</a>` in the template. It maybe works too.