# How to handle Binary response in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, blob

I am getting a xlsx as binary response and i need to download it in the client side on click of a button. Please let me know.

I tried the option with blob but my response is corrupted.

Comment: Angulars `Http` has still several limitations. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368633/angular-2-download-pdf-from-api-and-display-it-in-view/37051365#37051365 might help.

Comment: Can ArrayBuffer help here? it was added in commit several days ago, I think. https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/1266460386fe34c9e0f022b8cd1be311f3b58b9a