# convert string/Text to byte array in type script

Tags: angularjs, http, typescript, angular, blob

I am Currently working on task to download file (PDF/excel/text) using secure API in my system in angular 2 (beta) version.

I have used post API with authentication header and trying to create blob using data bytes received.

I have tried using following code

```
return this.http.get(url, { headers: this.headers}).map( response => response.blob())
```

But, i got the error that blob method is not implemented in angular 2 HTTP.

so i am trying following code where i need to convert string to byte array.

```
return this.http.get(Configuration.API_URL + url, { headers: this.headers }).map(
            response => {
                var bytes = [];

                var utf8 = encodeURIComponent(response.text());
                for (var i = 0; i < utf8.length; i++) {
                    bytes.push(utf8.charCodeAt(i));
                }    
                var data = new Blob([bytes], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(data);
                window.open(fileURL);
            }
        );
```

here i am facing some issue with the bytes array. Byte array is not same as the one sent by the API.

Need help in either converting string to byte array  or using blob in angular 2 HTTP get request.

Comment: Yes, blob() is coming soon. Meanwhile, please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368633/angular-2-download-pdf-from-api-and-display-it-in-view

Comment: Thankyou mico

this xhr answer helped me

Comment: What is the difference between the byte arrays ? all elements or only header/footer ?

Comment: I have used this module: http://alferov.github.io/angular-file-saver/ for downloading excel files.
Let me know if you need to see the actual code i have written.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, The below npm package can help you convert it into ByteArray.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xdata

Hope it helps you!

Cheers!