# Angular 4 download .pdf link

Tags: angular, pdf, download

We have a database of .pdf links on Sharepoint.  Using Angular 2/4, we want to display a table of these documents.

One of the requirements, is for the user to click on one of the icons in the table and the .pdf file to be streamed to the browser, so in chrome a message displays "Open or Save".  I have seen something similar done in Angular beta ([Angular 2 download PDF from API and Display it in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368633/angular-2-download-pdf-from-api-and-display-it-in-view)), but wondered, if there is a better way to do this.

As a further requirement, then is to "Select All" and then zip each .pdf into its own file and stream the zip.  We are using .NET Core Web API and assume this would be the place to undertake the zipping and then process it using the same method as above,

Any guidance on this would be useful.

Regards

Mark

Comment: with regard to displaying the url its easy make a http get call in angular and get all the url in a array and then  using a structural directive ngFor iterate through the array and display the contents inside of a table inside of a anchor tag href . and this will help you open and save the url inside of chrome. With regard to select all and zip have you tried something so far ?

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet, but guess might be looking at  third-party option on the server-side.

Comment: first try and implement the other two logics and then procced , and if you face issues post it on stack