# Download file not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Javascript, I want to download a file that comes from a dynamic url after the result of a promise, it is a generated pdf which I am trying to download with the following call but unable to make it work as download doesn't start.

```
<button (click)='downloadMyFile()'>Download</button>

downloadMyFile(){
  //url 
  .then((result)=>{
   //result is contains a url www.abc.com/file234
    window.location.href = result
})
  .catch((error)=>{
   //myerror
})
}
```

Here is [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/vlu7aUQ6d3hK8fP1NNJO?p=preview)

Comment: What is the content of `result`?

Comment: @meskobalazs  when in postman I get a dialogbox saying to download file. it is a downloadable file.

Comment: What happens when you open the result url in your browser? Alternatively you can wrap the button in an `<a>` and just set the href on that once retrieved for a less javascript-y way of opening it.

Comment: isn't using a tag around button invalid ? the url pass some dynamic data which uses that value to get me a file.

Comment: your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: please edit your question with server API

Comment: go to your plnkr, and you can follow my answer.

Comment: My answer here should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/48467727

Comment: Try to enter the url into your browser directly and if the download doesn't start this may help: if you load a file using a restful service (looks like you are using one) or request a file without extension make sure to include the mime type in the server response so it is recognized as a file.

Answer (score 8):

You can force download file like this:

```
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = result;
link.download = 'download';
link.target = '_blank';
link.click();
```

Simply create anchor tag, set its `href` and `download` attributes and trigger `click` event.

Also note that this is not really about URL ending with extension or not - it is more about the headers that you send with the file response (namely `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition`).

Answer (score 1):

```
<button (click)='downloadMyFile()'>Download</button>

downloadMyFile(){
  .then((result)=>{
       var a= document.createElement('a');
       a.href = result;
       a.download = 'download name';
       a.click();
   }).catch((error)=>{})
}
```

Comment: What is the technic called? The syntax seems alien to me.

Comment: I will try, what if my ApiService take long to reply, How can I mock data with some url that doesn't end with a file extension?

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of codes:

```
    //redirect current page to success page
    window.location="www.example.com/success.html";
    window.focus();
```

OR You can use `pdf.js` from http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

```
    PDFJS.getDocument({ url: pdf_url }).then(function(pdf_doc) {
        __PDF_DOC = pdf_doc;
        __TOTAL_PAGES = __PDF_DOC.numPages;

        // Hide the pdf loader and show pdf container in HTML
        $("#pdf-loader").hide();
        $("#pdf-contents").show();
        $("#pdf-total-pages").text(__TOTAL_PAGES);

        // Show the first page
        showPage(1);
    }).catch(function(error) {

        alert(error.message);
    });;
```

Source and Complete code: http://usefulangle.com/post/20/pdfjs-tutorial-1-preview-pdf-during-upload-wih-next-prev-buttons

Answer (score 0):

instead of making ajax request to download file just do the following.

```
window.open(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

(3 different files) in `app.module.ts` :

```
 import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
 ...
 providers: [
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
```

in `api.service.ts` :

```
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
...
public getMeMyPDF(): any {
    const url =  '/my/api/for/pdf';
    this.PDF = this.http.get(url, {
      observe: 'response',
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type', 'application/pdf'}),
      responseType: 'text' as 'text' // <-- this part is rediculous but necessary
    }).catch(this.handleError);
    return this.PDF;
}

handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  console.log('an http get error happened.');
  console.error(error);
  let errorMessage;
  if (error.error instanceof Error) {
    errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${error.error.message}`;
  } else {
    errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${error.status}, error message is: ${error.message}`;
  }
  console.error(errorMessage);
  return errorMessage;
}
```

and in `my.component.that.calls.api` :

```
getMeAPDF(){
    this.apiService.getMeMyPDF().subscribe(res => {
      if(res !== null && res !== undefined){
        this.saveToFileSystem(res.body);
      }
    }, (error) => console.log(error), () => {});
  }

  private saveToFileSystem(response) {
    const blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'text/pdf' });
    const d = new Date();
    saveAs(blob, 'WOWPDF_' + this._datepipe.transform(d, 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss') + '.pdf');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `saveAs()` function with `npm install @types/file-saver --save-dev`

or in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3"
  }
```

**Sample to export CSV file:**

HTML:

```
<button (click)="exportCsv()" id="exportCsv" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">CSV Export</button>
```

Component:

```
import { FooService } from '../services/foo.service';

constructor(private fooService: FooService) { }

async exportCsv() {
  this.fooService.exportCsv(this.fooid);
}
```

Service (fooService):

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import { HttpParams, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';

exportCsv(fooid: string) {
    let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('fooid', fooid);
    this.apiService.getCSVFile('api/foo/export', params).subscribe(response => this.saveToFileSystem(response)
    , error =>  this.errorProcessor(error));
}

private saveToFileSystem(response: HttpResponse<Blob>) {
    const contentDispositionHeader = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
    let filename = 'export.csv';
    if (contentDispositionHeader !== null) {
      const parts: string[] = contentDispositionHeader.split(';');
      filename = parts[1].split('=')[1];
    }
    const blob = response.body;
    if (blob !== null) {
        saveAs(blob, filename);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the response of your promise like mentioned below:

```
 var triggerDownload = function(url, fileName) {
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.setAttribute("href", url);
      a.setAttribute("download", fileName);
      opts.container.append(a);
      a.click();
      $(a).remove();
  };

  downloadMyFile() {
      promise
       .then((result) => {
          triggerDownload(result, 'xyz.pdf'); 
        })
       .catch((error) => {
          //myerror
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works for downloadign the API respone in IE and chrome/safari. Here response variable is API response.

```
 let blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    let fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileUrl.split(':')[1] + '.pdf');
    } else {
        window.open(fileUrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can download any dynamic file by just write a download in the tag where you have fetch the url to the file. try this and let me know if it work for you.

> here is the working example:

```
<a href="http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf" download>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not really required for this, so I will suggest the laziest and easiest possible solution - to simply use a basic html tag instead.

Instead of a button, use an anchor tag with the download keyword:

```
<a href="www.abc.com/file234" download="SuggestedFileName">Download</a>
```

Very old browsers that does not support HTML5 will fail elegantly - instead of downloading the target, older browsers will simply display the target in the browser. That's very graceful degradation and a fully acceptable fallback.

You can style the anchor to look like whatever you want with css, and  is also the most semantically correct tag: anchors are for links (and this is a link) while buttons are for interacting with forms (like submit) or other interactions with the UI. THe end user won't know or care what tag you use anyway.

If the url will be changed, like getting different parameters based on interactions with the UI, you could always use javascript to update the URL on the tag - but that is a different question.

[Reference for Anchor tag on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)