# Open PDF file in new tab

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Open PDF file in new tab using Angular 6. I tried this:

*Rest controller:*

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/downloads")
public class DownloadsController {

    private static final String EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH = "/Users/test/Documents/blacklist_api.pdf";

    @GetMapping("export")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> export() throws IOException {
        ClassPathResource pdfFile = new ClassPathResource(EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        headers.add("Expires", "0");

        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentLength(pdfFile.contentLength())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
                .body(new InputStreamResource(pdfFile.getInputStream()));
    }
}
```

*Service:*

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DownloadService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  exportPdf() {
    return this.http.get(environment.api.urls.downloads.getPdf,  { responseType: 'blob' });
  }
}
```

*Component:*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-download',
  templateUrl: './download.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./download.component.scss']
})
export class DownloadComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private downloadService: DownloadService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  export() {     
     window.open(this.downloadService.exportPdf());
  }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<h1 class="title">Export</h1>

<div class="content grid-wrapper">

  <div class="export">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="export()">Export</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

What is the proper wya to implement the Angular service and component in order to open the PDF document into new tab when I click the button?

Can you advice?

Comment: You can't just use response from backend. You have to create Blob object and then create link and open it automatically or use for `<embed>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app for more details.
@edit: thread is for Angular.JS but the part you need is written in vanilla js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368633/angular-2-download-pdf-from-api-and-display-it-in-view this should help

Comment: I updated the answer with the implementation that I tried to implement but still I get error. Can you advice how to fix it?

Comment: can you post the response you are getting from server ?

Comment: With the above code I get new tab with the same page: PDF document is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
export() {
    this.downloadService.exportPdf();
}
```

...

```
exportPdf(){
     window.open(environment.api.urls.downloads.getPdf);
}
```

Comment: This is for the component of for the service?

Comment: the service. get rig of the `ngOnInit` in the component. and just call the services new `export` from the components `export`

Comment: Can you update you answer please with working example?

Comment: I updated the code that I tried to implement but when I press the button nothing happens. Any idea why?

Comment: Well I get "Full authentication is required to access this resource". Why window.open should be placed into the service? Maybe it should be placed into the component?

Comment: I updated the post. But now I new tab with the same page.